# What is cross validation good for, exactly?

Tags: python, regression, cross-validation, overfitting

I keep seeing that cross validation is a good way to reduce overfitting, but, in my case, I don't see how it helps much. Let me explain:

I'm interested in running a Multinomial Logit for prediction, with 3 classes on the dependent variable.

I saw that cross validation is good to tune hyperparameters, which makes sense, but in my case I don't have any hyperparameters to test. What good is it for then? Just checking that the accuracy on "different" datasets, with the same features, doesn't vary much?

Let's say after a Stratified k-folds approach I get a mean accuracy and precision on the test set of 90%. Is this enough to say my model, with those features I selected, is not overfitted?

Comment: ask your second question in another question.

Comment: @PedroHenriqueMonforte ah I wasn't sure. Thanks, I just did that